# Leaflet on-click circle doesn't work in Python folium

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

I would like to make the Leaflet circle an on-click feature in my Python folium map.

Unfortunately, the code returns nothing despite no information from the console.

```
class Circle(MacroElement):
"""
    https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle
"""

_template = Template(
"""
{% macro script(this, kwargs) %}  
  function newCircle(e){
   var circle_job = L.Circle().setLatLng(e.latlng).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
   }
         {% endmacro %}
 """
)
```

job_range = Circle()

map.add_child(job_range)

What have I done wrong here?